# Creation of a column based on filtered values of other column in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, data-cleaning

I try to create a new variable called `k` which its values depends if `metric` is **I** or **M**, otherwise I want to return an empty value.

Thanks in advance for your answer :)

```
data = [["1", "Amit", "DU", "I", "8", "6"],
        ["2", "Mohit", "DU", "I", "4", "2"],
        ["3", "rohith", "BHU", "I", "5", "3"],
        ["4", "sridevi", "LPU", "I", "1", "6"],
        ["1", "sravan", "KLMP", "M", "2", "4"],
        ["5", "gnanesh", "IIT", "M", "6", "8"],
       ["6", "gnadesh", "KLM", "c", "10", "9"]]

columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'college', 'metric', 'x', 'y']


dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

```
+---+-------+-------+------+---+---+
| ID|   NAME|college|metric|  x|  y|
+---+-------+-------+------+---+---+
|  1|   Amit|     DU|     I|  8|  6|
|  2|  Mohit|     DU|     I|  4|  2|
|  3| rohith|    BHU|     I|  5|  3|
|  4|sridevi|    LPU|     I|  1|  6|
|  1| sravan|   KLMP|     M|  2|  4|
|  5|gnanesh|    IIT|     M|  6|  8|
|  6|gnadesh|    KLM|     c| 10|  9|
+---+-------+-------+------+---+---+
```

I tried to use this but it does not work

```
dataframe= dataframe.withColumn('k', when ((col('metric') == 'M',(dataframe['metric'] / 10)))
                                              .when ((col('metric') == 'I',(dataframe['metric'] / 10 * 2,54)))
                                              .otherwise (' '))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

dataframe= dataframe.withColumn('k', when ((col('metric') == 'M',(dataframe['metric'] / 10)))
                                          .when ((col('metric') == 'I',(dataframe['metric'] / 10 * 2,54)))
                                          .otherwise (lit(' ')))
```

Or

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

dataframe= dataframe.withColumn('k', when ((col('metric') == 'M',(dataframe['metric'] / 10)))
                                          .when ((col('metric') == 'I',(dataframe['metric'] / 10 * 2,54)))
                                          .otherwise (lit(None)))
```

I am guessing you're getting the error in the `otherwise` part of the code. The argument for `DataFrame.withColumn` should be of type `Column`, which `' '` isn't.